# Similar Right Triangles and Incircles

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Triangle and Incircle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104255/triangle-and-incircle)

In a setup of right triangles ABC, BDA, and BDC not unlike this

[diagram](http://www.stopdown.net/myjpeg/math__rudy__rt__rudy__triangle2.JPG)

(click on the link, and ignore the written side measures and subtext in that diagram- we don't know any side-lengths here)

The incircle(inscribed circle) of triangle BDA has radius=5 and the incircle of BDC has radius=3. What is the radius of the incircle of ABC?

Answer (score 1):

The two smaller triangles are **similar** to each other, and to the big triangle.  This is fairly easy to see, the angles match.

What this means informally is that if we put $\triangle ABC$ in a Xerox machine, then with the suitable *Reduce* setting we get one of the other triangles, and with another *Reduce* setting, you get the other one.

If $\triangle BDA$ has incircle of radius $p$, and $\triangle BDC$ has incircle of radius $q$, then because one is a scaled version of the other, the hypotenuses of the two triangles are also in the ratio $p:q$.  Say the hypotenuses are respectively $kp$ and $kq$.

By the Pythagorean Theorem, the hypotenuse of $\triangle ABC$ is $\sqrt{(kp)^2+(kq)^2}=k\sqrt{p^2+q^2}$.

So the hypotenuses of the three triangles are in the ratio 
$$p: q: \sqrt{p^2+q^2}.$$

The incircle radii are in the same ratio. So if the two little ones are $p$ and $q$, the big one is $\sqrt{p^2+q^2}$.